# SSH with multiple virtual machins

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm currently on amazon's aws, what I'm trying to do is to create two virtual machines, the first is the master VM named "master" and the second is the slave VM named "node1".

I would like to run a program on the VM master for tasks to be distributed on the slave machine. If everything works fine, i would like to create several slaves and create a parallelism system.

On amazon aws,  to connect to virtual machines we must use a xxx.pem file generated by the aws to identify myself by ssh -i "xxx.pem" xxx@xxx

But in my case I created a "master" user in the master VM and then generated a blank password by doing ssh-keygen -t rsa. I copied and pasted on a "authorized_keys" file on the /home/node1/.ssh/ of the slave VM that i created myself.

Now when I try to do an ssh node1@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx he asks me for a password... i dont understand why ?

After trying everything i can't connect with ssh name@private_ip , he asked me an password each time.

What should i do ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In order to debug this, run `sshd -D -p 8022 -ddd` on the slave node, and `ssh -vvv -p 8022 name@private_ip`. A common mistake is to have write access to anything leading to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and you should double check that first.

Comment: 2 weeks on the SSH problem, still not find the solution .. always this message: Permission denied (publickey) or Connection refused.

I think its impossible to create my own ssh connexion between several VM

Comment: why don't you post the logs ? (note you likely have to `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 8022 -ddd` to run the SSH server). you might also want to double check in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` rsa keys are allowed (or feel free to post the content of the file)

Answer (score 0):

Server side log :

```
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-17 ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-172-31-35-17 ec2-user]# /usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 8022 -ddd
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 728
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 728
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:22 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:24 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:25 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:32 setting SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:40 setting PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:49 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:65 setting PasswordAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:70 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:97 setting UsePAM yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:102 setting X11Forwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:107 setting PrintLastLog yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:110 setting UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:127 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:128 setting AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:129 setting AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:130 setting AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:133 setting Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:sHblS+34MhcBEtE/kCxfAoJ1fcZJyu4tYZKdcDEeQ4E
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:BLgYMx1fFNlmkUpwqdp61g98k+ojM2TV2L1KYPmYdao
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:/SXACNF7WrrjPDcCsxFYX6Km9jfyAtA0pisg6VFxxIM
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='8022'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-ddd'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 8022 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 8022.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 8022 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 8022.
```

Comment: please edit your question with the logs (otherwise your answer will be removed because it is indeed not an answer). You only posted the logs related to the initialisation (which is not interesting in that case). you need to `ssh -vvv -p 8022 name@private_ip` on the master host. This will generate `ssh` logs (interesting) and have the remote `sshd` generate more traces (very interesting that will tell you exactly why login was denied.